# Using Hibernate in case of a common table which holds metadata for several tables

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the below scenario :

There is one table which maintains the metadata related to several entities. Below is the schema and how the table would look like :

[image: Sample Table]

Both `TABLE_A` and `TABLE_B` are mapped as Hibernate Entities and are backed by `ClassA` and `ClassB`. 
Now, how can I map this table in Hibernate such that I can achieve the below scenario :

```
ClassA classA = aService.getById("1234");

ClassB classB = bService.getById("1234");

classA.getAttributeValue(); -- Should return 12ab

classB.getAttributeValue(); -- Should return cs12
```

Is there a way where Hibernate can intelligently get the `AttributeValue` based on the type of the object from which the method is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [Single table inheritance](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#d5e3306). So your classes could look like this:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(
    name="entityType",
    discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING
)
@DiscriminatorValue("TABLE_A")
public class ClassA {
     @Id
     private String id;

     @Column(name = "ATTRIBUTE_NAME")
     private String name;

     @Column(name = "ATTRIBUTE_VALUE")
     private String value;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("TABLE_B")
public class ClassB extends ClassA { ... }
```

An alternative would be creating a common ancestor class and have `Table_A` mapped to it's own subclass entity.

Comment: Almost correct, I just don't like `ClassB` inheriting `ClassA`. A common ancestor class would be much better.

Comment: @AdamDyga I'm more worried about `@Id` here, but I'm looking into that.

Comment: Thanks much. This solves my problem pretty much. But, is there a way to use the Discriminator column without making ClassA and ClassB subclasses of a superclass(say ClassSuper)?

Comment: @VamseeKrishna If there is, I'm not aware of it. If you're not "just" running two entities into the same table (using `@Table` and getting burned by it), but want Hibernate to distinguish between entries, the framework has to view these as "related" somehow. This is the reason behind the superclass. So having one is conceptually useful/needed.